# Breeze controller metadata with unmapped properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a property that is not mapped into my database. I've used the Ignore method in my database layer:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Ignore(c => c.Translations);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Manufacturer>().Ignore(c => c.Translations);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(c => c.Translations);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SpecificationAttribute>().Ignore(c => c.Translations);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SpecificationAttributeOption>().Ignore(c => c.Translations);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

This is an example of my class/entity:

```
public class SpecificationAttribute
{      

    private ICollection<Translation> _translations;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations
    {
        get { return _translations ?? (_translations = new List<Translation>()); }
        set { _translations = value; }
    }        

}

public class Translation : BaseEntity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string KeyGroup { get; set; } 
    public string Key { get; set; } 
    public string Value { get; set; }        
}
```

I only want to use the **Translations** property on the Breeze client and not save/change anything on my database. So I've created a piece of code that fill the **Translations** property when I call the Breeze Method.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SpecificationAttributes")]
public IQueryable<SpecificationAttribute> SpecificationAttributes()
{
    var collection = _contextProvider.Context.SpecificationAttributes;
    collection.ForEach(x => x.Translations = _contextProvider.Context.Translations.Where(y => y.EntityId == x.Id && y.KeyGroup == typeof(SpecificationAttribute).Name).ToList());
    return collection;
}
```

When I call this method manually everything is working fine and the result includes the **Translations**. But when I call this function with the breeze client on my angular app, the **Translations** are not included. Does anyone knows what the problem could be? I've already tried to use the expand command, but then I get an error.

Comment: You should register a type ctor to initialize the unmapped properties/collection

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with extending the property on the beeze client.

***code - entityManagerFactory.js***

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory("entityManagerFactory", entityManagerFactory);
    entityManagerFactory.$inject = ["config", "model"];

    function entityManagerFactory(config, model) {
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('modelLibrary', 'backingStore', true);
        //breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();

        // Tell breeze not to validate when we attach a newly created entity to any manager.
        // We could also set this per entityManager
        new breeze.ValidationOptions({ validateOnAttach: false }).setAsDefault();

        var serviceName = config.remoteApiUrl + "/breeze/";
        var metadataStore = createMetadataStore();

        var provider = {
            metadataStore: metadataStore,
            newManager: newManager
        };

        return provider;

        function createMetadataStore() {
            var store = new breeze.MetadataStore();
   ------>  model.configureMetadataStore(store);
            return store;
        }

        function newManager() {
            var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({
                serviceName: serviceName,
                metadataStore: metadataStore,
                saveOptions: new breeze.SaveOptions({ allowConcurrentSaves: false })
            });
            return mgr;
        }
    }
})();
```

***Piece of code - model.js***

```
function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {       
    registerSpecificationAttribute(metadataStore);
    registerSpecificationAttributeOption(metadataStore);
}

function registerSpecificationAttribute(metadataStore) {

    function SpecificationAttribute() {
        this.Translations = [];
    }

    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("SpecificationAttribute", SpecificationAttribute);

}

function registerSpecificationAttributeOption(metadataStore) {

    function SpecificationAttributeOption() {
        this.Translations = [];
    }

    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("SpecificationAttributeOption", SpecificationAttributeOption);

}
```